# Fixing an unresolved reference in my calculator?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm doing a calculator build online and I keep receiving an "Unresolved reference" error on the word operation and the first string wont run, but everything after will. It's also saying that operation is "Undefined". I looked in the tutorial and online but I cant seem to find a fix. I cleared the caches and restarted and it worked for a few moments and then said the same thing. I've included the code and the error text.

```
def calculate():
    operation = input('''
Welcome to my Calculator\nChoose the math operation you want to use:
+ ~ Add
- ~ Sub
* ~ Mul
/ ~ Div
''')


number_1 = float(input("OK\nEnter your first number:  "))
number_2 = float(input("Enter your second number:  "))
if operation == '+':
    print('{} + {} = '.format(number_1, number_2))
    print(number_1 + number_2)
elif operation == '-':
    print('{} - {} = '.format(number_1, number_2))
    print(number_1 - number_2)
elif operation == '*':
    print('{} * {} ='.format(number_1, number_2))
    print(number_1 * number_2)
elif operation == '/':
    print('{} / {} ='.format(number_1, number_2))
    print(number_1 / number_2)
else:
    print('You must choose an Operator.\n+  -  *  /')
# Call calculate() out side the function
calculate()
```

---

- List item

line 14, in 
if operation == '+':
NameError: name 'operation' is not defined

Comment: You need to fix indentation of your code. As of now the `calculate()` only takes input in `operation`, nothing more. So, when you run your code, before the call to `calculate()` is encountered, `operation` is referenced. That is why the error

Comment: Can you comment on where exactly the indentation is wrong?

Comment: All the `number_1=...`, `number_2=...` and the if else block should have same indentation as `operation=...`. That way the whole thing will be part of `calculate()` function. Last line i.e. call to `calculate()` is correct

Comment: Oh...I didn't realize indentation was so important! Thank you, it worked!